# Joining back tables to get the rest of the data

Tags: mysql

I've run this code:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_term_relationships.object_id AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = '10' 
LEFT JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = 'US' AND wp_posts.post_date BETWEEN CONCAT(CURDATE(),' 10:00:00') AND CONCAT(CURDATE(),' 18:00:00')
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_shipping_country' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value IN ('AU', 'US', 'JP', 'BR', 'UK')
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.post_id DESC
```

Which is simply selecting `wp_postmeta.meta_key` and `wp_postmeta.meta_value` where they are equal to `_shipping_country` and `AU`.

There is a lot more data in these fields that needs to be retrieved.

So, I'm assuming I join it back together at the end like this:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_term_relationships.object_id AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = '10' 
LEFT JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = 'US' AND wp_posts.post_date BETWEEN CONCAT(CURDATE(),' 10:00:00') AND CONCAT(CURDATE(),' 18:00:00')
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_shipping_country' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value IN ('AU', 'US', 'JP', 'BR', 'UK')
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.post_id DESC
```

However this fails?

Answer (score 0):

Updated the query so it should return all data for orders that have a shipping_country matching 'AU', 'US', 'JP', 'BR' or 'UK'.

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_term_relationships.object_id AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = '10' 
LEFT JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id AND wp_posts.post_date BETWEEN CONCAT(CURDATE(),' 10:00:00') AND CONCAT(CURDATE(),' 18:00:00')
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta pm2 WHERE pm2.post_id = wp_posts.id AND pm2.meta_key = '_shipping_country' AND pm2.meta_value IN ('AU', 'US', 'JP', 'BR', 'UK'))
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.post_id DESC
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this does not work. I get "NOT UNIQUE ALIAS/TABLE".

Comment: I read too quickly. The wp_postmeta table is already part of the query, so I'm not sure why you're trying to add it again.

Comment: Well, yeah, neither am I to be honest. I'm highly confused. I want to select ALL the orders from wp_postmeta.meta_key and wp_postmeta.meta_value but only where the post is shipping country in that array. Perhaps I need to move this to chat to really tell you what is going on.

Comment: Basically the current statement is only showing the row with _shipping_country and "AU". It should also include a lot more. It shows: http://i.imgur.com/cnDfE.png. I want all this: http://i.imgur.com/YBaGq.jpg but only where it is associated with those above conditions. Do you understand?

Comment: Okay, so you want to get all the meta data for the orders that were shipped to 'AU', 'US', 'JP', 'BR' or 'UK'? Let me update my answer

Comment: Yes, but also if it was US the BETWEEN gets run. It doesn't get run on any other country.

Comment: Updated again to remove the us only clause

Comment: The US clause gets run if the order is for US... 

So something like `wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_shipping_country' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = 'US'` ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15293/discussion-between-dean-and-thevedge)